# Getting 'no token provided error' with react (jsx)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session, jsx, token

Attempting to set up user authentication on my web app so i can navigate through my site while staying signed in. I have attached the code below. Can't get to the bottom of it, hopefully missing something small just! If anyone can see where I've gone wrong please let me know!

```
const SECRET_KEY = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY;

function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1]; 

  if (token == null) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "No token provided." });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Token verification error:", err);
      return res.status(403).json({ message: "Token verification failed." });
    }

    console.log("Decoded token payload:", user); 

    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
}
```

```
app.post("/user/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    console.log("Received login request for email:", email);

  
    console.log("SECRET_KEY:", SECRET_KEY);

    const getUserQuery = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?";
    db.query(getUserQuery, [email], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Error fetching user data." });
      }

      if (result.length === 0) {
        console.log("User not found for email:", email);
        return res.status(403).json({ message: "Wrong email or password" });
      }

      const user = result[0];

    
      const storedHashedPassword = user.password.toString();

     
      bcrypt.compare(password, storedHashedPassword, (err, passwordValid) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: "Error comparing passwords." });
        }

        if (passwordValid) {
          
          const token = jwt.sign({ email, user_id: user.user_id }, SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: "1h",
          });

          
          console.log("Generated token:", token);
          res.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`); 

          res.json({
            message: "Authentication successful!",
            token,
            userInfo: {
              user_id: user.user_id,
            },
          });
        } else {
        
          return res.status(403).json({ message: "Wrong email or password" });
        }
      }); 
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Something went wrong." });
  }
});
```

I think it has something to do with the token not being passed to the front end properly?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import AccountDashboard from "../AccountDashboard";
import axios from "axios";

function Account() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const { userId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fetching user data for userId:", userId);
  
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:8081/account/${userId}`;
    console.log("API URL:", apiUrl);
  
    const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken"); 
    console.log("Token:", token);
  
    if (token) {
      axios.get(apiUrl, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Fetched User Data:", response.data);
        if (response.data.user_name) {
          setUser(response.data);
        } else {
          setUser(null);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error fetching user data:", err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("No token found in localStorage");
    }
  }, [userId]);
  
  console.log("User State:", user);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="account-dashboard">
        {user !== null ? <AccountDashboard user={user} /> : <p>Loading user data...</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Account;
```

This is the output I am getting with console.log() statements:

`User State: null Account.jsx:11 Fetching user data for userId: 14 Account.jsx:14 API URL: http://localhost:8081/account/14 Account.jsx:17 Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFpbmVAeWFob28uY29tIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTQsImlhdCI6MTY5MjE4Mzk1NSwiZXhwIjoxNjkyMTg3NTU1fQ.yZ0e3FuYcEGFyvth8hSwaw4_cIVnn_YYJ0GPbXiTaPc Account.jsx:34 Error fetching user data: AxiosError`